# how to give different sides of the system to different authorized users in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have a system that is suppose to give different users to access different parts of the system like if manager logs in, he can view everything except to perform database backup else the menus for reports and adding new products should be disabled.

This is what I have but it doesn't do what I want it to:

```
Con.close()
Con.open()
Query = "select emp_id,password,job from employees where emp_id ='" & txtusername.text & "'"
Command = new sqlcommand(query,con)
Dr = cmd.executereader
'Dr is sqldatareader
If dr.read = true then 
    If dr(2) = "Manager" then
       Frmmainmenu.show()
    Else
       Frmmainmenu.show()
       Frmmainmenu.show.reports.enabled = false
    End if
Else
    Msgbox("incorrect login credentials")
End if
Me.hide()
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what does `it doesn't do what I want it to` mean.  can you be more specific?

Comment: If a Manager logs in, it suppose to give him access to everything except to perform back up,the system is a desktop ordering system. So if manager logins, all menus should be enabled except backup menu on the main_menu form. Else if the user is not a manager, the menu for viewing reports,adding new products should be disabled and backup menu should be enabled now!! I'm not sure if that's more specific!!

Comment: thats just restating the post: what **doesnt** it do or how is it broke? is there an error? a) use SQL parameters b) instance your forms c) that way you can disable things before you show them.  What kind of thing is "reports" on the main menu? `Frmmainmenu.show.reports` is wrong - Show has no such method or property.